# Ajax datepicker sends in correct GB format, but gets to viewModel tries to parse as US format

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

I have a datePicker on my site, and i use the value to send via Ajax request to my ActionResult which takes in a viewModel seen:

```
public int UserID { get; set; }
    //1-CreatedBy,2 - AssignedTo, 3 - UpdatedBy
    public int UserFilterTypeID { get; set; }
    public int TaskTypeID { get; set; }
    public int TaskStatusID { get; set; }
    public HelperClass.Priority Priority{get; set; }

    // 1-DateCreated 2-DateUpdated
    public int DateTypeID { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime DateFrom { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime DateTo { get; set; }
```

the datepicker is set up like this

```
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        regional: "en-GB"
    });
```

when the ajax parameters are inspected dateFrom shows 18/12/2014 (18th Dec 2014), but when inspect the values from the viewModel on the actionResult dateFrom shows 01/01/0001 00:00:000 (default date) as if it can't parse the date because its expecting US Format, but i've set displayFormat to dd/mm/yyyy in the ViewModel and set the datepicker settings to dd/mm/yy so should be in GB regional settings.

please help people

Comment: What is the culture setting on the server? If its not `en-GB` (or another culture that uses `dd/MM/yyyy`) then the `DefaultModelBinder` wont bind it (you would need to create a custom model binder). The display format has nothing to do with it - that's for determining how the date is formatted in the view. And using `ApplyFormatInEditMode` is not necessary (that's only used by `@Html.EditorFor()` and in any case it needs to be `"{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"` to be used in the browsers HTML5 datepicker)

Answer (score -1):

Try to use type String instead of DateTime. It is not a best solution but it works